# Decrypt des with openssl_decrypt in PHP

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, php-5.6

Trying to decrypt a single des encrypted data using this code:

```
$keyValue ='0123456789abcdef'; //hex value
$encryptedOrderId = '88C10F0B8C084E5F'; //hex value
$binaryEncrypted = hex2bin($encryptedOrderId);
$decodeValueByOnlineTool = '2020202039353538';  // this is hex
$opensslDecrypt = openssl_decrypt(  $encryptedOrderId  ,'DES-ECB', $keyValue, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA , '' );
var_dump($opensslDecrypt);
```

The output is false. I do not know what wrong I'm doing.

The output from my tool is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Do you not find it odd that you aren't using `keyValue` in your call to `openssl_decrypt`?  Did you actually write that code or have you copied it from somewhere without understanding it?  I suggest you read the docs for [`openssl_decrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php).

Comment: sorry for that I some how deleted it from my code check my updates.

Comment: DES keys are 64-bits (including parity) in length but the (hint: *hex*) string that you are passing in is interpreted as being 128-bits.  Can you figure out what is wrong from that?  Obviously the warning you have is relevant too.

Comment: not actually ,please give an answer if it works i'll mark it correct. you mean to say I need to convert it to binary?

Comment: Yes, you do.  And fix the IV.  I think that one is self explanatory.

Comment: `$opensslDecrypt = openssl_decrypt(  hex2bin($encryptedOrderId)  ,'DES-ECB', $keyValue ,  OPENSSL_RAW_DATA , '' );` I tried this but still the output is empty string. but no warning.

Comment: You need to convert your hex key string to binary...

Comment: please show me in answer just the steps. because I think I'm doing the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inputs are in hex.  `openssl_decrypt` expects binary.  Use `hex2bin` on each input before passing to `openssl_decrypt`.

```
openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($encryptedOrderId), 'DES-ECB', hex2bin($keyValue), ...
```

Remember to convert the result back into hex to get the result you want.  Make sure you've set `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` as per your screenshot.

EDIT: The exact code I used...

```
$keyValue ='0123456789abcdef'; //hex value
$encryptedOrderId = '88C10F0B8C084E5F'; //hex value
$binaryEncrypted = hex2bin($encryptedOrderId);
$decodeValueByOnlineTool = '2020202039353538';  // this is hex
$opensslDecrypt = openssl_decrypt( $binaryEncrypted  ,'des-ecb', hex2bin($keyValue), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING , '');
var_dump($opensslDecrypt);
```

Comment: I did that too. returns false.

Comment: With the no padding?

Comment: with OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING in 4th parameter. empty string output

Comment: See the exact code I used above.  Definitely works for me.

Comment: letme check it .

Comment: Thank you it works, I'm not sure why both OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING and OPENSSL_RAW_DATA are required.

Comment: Because your code requires that there is zero padding and that you are using raw data...

Comment: but when I use OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING only it does not work.

Comment: That is because you are passing raw data to the function... the `hex2bin` calls...  So the function thinks you are passing in an encoded string instead, which you aren't, so it doesn't work.